# Java method to find Standard Deviation

Tags: java, statistics, data-science

I'm a novice programmer who is making a personal library for statistics using Java.

I wrote the following code and I'm facing no problems at all, however when I run this method the value of standard deviation (which it is returning) is off after 3 decimal points.[image]

the mean() above is working fine.

It would also be helpful, if some of you give me some tips on how to write my code more effectively.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode